Python Unit Test ModuleNotFoundError with local Module
My directory structure is like so:
src
├──__init__.py
├──config.py
├──util.py
├──log.py
│   
└── tests
    ├── __init__.py
    └── SomeTest.py

When I run SomeTest.py via pipenv run pytest src/tests/unit I get ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config'
Inside SomeTest.py I have
from config import ConfigManager
Inside config.py I have
import util as util
I can't figure out why the test, when it imports config then has an issue with importing util from config
If I remove the config import it then complains it cannot find the log.py module.
